# Hide app (Air for Android) from the menu?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

I have an Android game developed in Adobe Flash Professional CS6 using action script 3. It's an AIR for Android App.

I've made another Android app (developed in Eclipse), which will launch the game. Without this app the user should not be able to play the game. i.e I want to hide the game from the main menu where all installed app are shown, so that user can not open the game directly.

There are two options which I want to achieve. Either hide the game`or`Let the game not be hidden but it should not open directly with my native app.

I've tried launching the game from my native app, and its fine and I'm able to Launch the game from my native app, but even I can play the game without my native app directly from main menu.

I've included the game AndroidManifest.xml which is created by Adobe Flash Professional CS6

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.2">
  <id>com.mygame.jumpingfrog</id>
  <versionNumber>1.0.0</versionNumber>
  <versionLabel>JumpingFrog</versionLabel>
  <filename>Jumping Frog</filename>
  <description/>
<!-- To localize the description, use the following format for the description element.<description><text xml:lang="en">English App description goes here</text><text xml:lang="fr">French App description goes here</text><text xml:lang="ja">Japanese App description goes here</text></description>-->
  <name>JumpingFrog</name>
<!-- To localize the name, use the following format for the name element.<name><text xml:lang="en">English App name goes here</text><text xml:lang="fr">French App name goes here</text><text xml:lang="ja">Japanese App name goes here</text></name>-->
  <copyright/>
  <initialWindow>
    <content>AndroidGameLoader.swf</content>
    <systemChrome>standard</systemChrome>
    <transparent>false</transparent>
    <visible>true</visible>
    <fullScreen>true</fullScreen>
    <aspectRatio>landscape</aspectRatio>
    <renderMode>gpu</renderMode>
    <autoOrients>false</autoOrients></initialWindow>
  <icon>
    <image36x36>36X36.png</image36x36>
    <image48x48>48X48.png</image48x48>
    <image72x72>72X72.png</image72x72>
  </icon>
  <customUpdateUI>false</customUpdateUI>
  <allowBrowserInvocation>false</allowBrowserInvocation>
  <android>
    <manifestAdditions>
      <![CDATA[<manifest>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
</manifest>]]>
    </manifestAdditions>
  </android>
  <supportedLanguages>en</supportedLanguages>
</application>
```

What do I need to do to achieve this?